# NSDocument + How to access saved versions programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument, versions

is there a way to access all the saved versions from a NSDocument without using the system versions viewer?

What I want is to access all the saved versions programmatically - like having an array or dictionary with all the versions inside...

Thanks,

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSFileVersion` like so: `[NSFileVersion unresolvedConflictVersionsOfItemAtURL:myDocument.fileURL]`

This will give you a list (poss. empty) of all conflicting versions of your NSDocument.